# Fail safe iterator - removal during iteration

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrenthashmap

> If fail safe iterator creates a clone of underlying data structure, why 'D' is never printed in program below?

```
Map<String, String> acMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
acMap.put("A", "Aye");
acMap.put("B", "Bee");
acMap.put("C", "See");
acMap.put("D", "Di");

Iterator<String> itr = acMap.keySet().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    acMap.remove("D");
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

Comment: missed that part. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the [Javadoc for `keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()):

> The iterator ... may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.

Your iterator *is* reflecting modifications subsequent to construction.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation any operation on map will reflect on keyset and vice versa. And `KeySet#iterator()` also does not clone the underlying ds.

[`ConcurrentHashMap#keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()):

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa. The set supports element removal, which removes the
>   corresponding mapping from this map, via the Iterator.remove,
>   Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations.

[Read more documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

[See openjdk Implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java?av=f)

Comment: It's more specific than the `keySet()`: it's the `keySet().iterator()` which is being used here.

Comment: ohk. One sec, what I can see `KeySet#iterator()` returns `KeyIterator` which is also does not clone the underlaying ds too. :)  [reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)